# Rmpi for conditional logisitc regression (clogit and coxph) using R

Tags: r, survival-analysis, logistic-regression

I'm trying to run a conditional logistic regression in a computing center with mulitple nodes to evaluate a big dataset of 969 million rows. But the calculation cancels because the job exceeds the maxmimum memory of 90GB of the node with the highest capacity.

I heard that the R package "Rmpi" makes it possible to run a calculation on mulitple nodes.

I'm using following code to run the conditional logit regression:

```
library(survival)
All <- read.table("/scratch/rvonscha/all.txt", header=TRUE, sep=";", na.strings="NA", dec=",", strip.white=TRUE)
attach(All)
model <- clogit(Alliance ~ OVB + BVB + CVC + EarlyStage + AvgVCSize +NumberVC + strata(Strata))
summary(model)
```

Is it possible to use Rmpi for this calculation and if yes, how can I implement it in the code?

I would really appreciate any help to solve this problem.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: As far as I see `coxph`, which does the actual model fit, does not provide a parallelization option. Why do you think it possible to parallelize this task? I would be somewhat surprised if it was.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether a parallelization is possible. I just tried to find a way to overcome the memory issue related to the analysis of my dataset.